Tap Gesture on Subview disables drag gesture on super view
I have the following two views in SwiftUI. The first view GestureTestView has a drag gesture defined on its overlay view (call it indicator view) and has the subview called ContentTestView that has tap gesture attached to it. The problem is tap gesture in ContentTestView is blocking Drag Gesture on indicator view. I have tried everything including simultaneous gestures but it doesn't seem to work as gestures are on different views. It's easy to test by simply copying and pasting the code and running the code in XCode preview.
import SwiftUI

struct GestureTestView: View {

   @State var indicatorOffset:CGFloat = 10.0

   var body: some View {
     
      ContentTestView()
         .overlay(alignment: .leading, content: {
        
             Capsule()
               .fill(Color.mint.gradient)
               .frame(width: 8, height: 60)
               .offset(x: indicatorOffset )
               .gesture(
                  DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged({ value in
                          indicatorOffset = min(max(0, 10 + value.translation.width), 340)

                    })
                    .onEnded { value in
                       
                    }
            )
       })
  }
}

 #Preview {
    GestureTestView()
 }

struct ContentTestView: View {

   @State var isSelected = false

   var body: some View {
       HStack(spacing:0) {
         ForEach(0..<8) { index in
              Rectangle()
                .fill(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                .frame(width:40, height:40)
          }
         .overlay {
             if isSelected {
                 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(.yellow, lineWidth: 3.0)
            }
          }
    }
     .onTapGesture {
         isSelected.toggle()
     }
    }
 }

#Preview {
   ContentTestView()
}


Changing the order of the modifiers fixes this. onTapGesture should come after overlay.
Here I have inlined ContentTestView into GestureTestView, and swapped the positions of overlay and onTapGesture.
struct GestureTestView: View {
    @State var indicatorOffset:CGFloat = 10.0
    @State var isSelected = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:0) {
            ForEach(0..<8) { index in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                    .frame(width:40, height:40)
            }
            .overlay {
                if isSelected {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(.yellow, lineWidth: 3.0)
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .leading, content: {
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.mint.gradient)
                .frame(width: 8, height: 60)
                .offset(x: indicatorOffset )
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            indicatorOffset = min(max(0, 10 + value.translation.width), 340)
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded { value in
                            
                        }
                )
        })
        .onTapGesture {
            isSelected.toggle()
        }
    }
}

Of course, it is better to break views up into smaller views. In this case, ContentTestView can take its overlay as a view builder closure.
struct ContentTestView<Overlay: View>: View {
    
    @State var isSelected = false
    
    let alignment: Alignment
    @ViewBuilder let overlay: () -> Overlay
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:0) {
            ForEach(0..<8) { index in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                    .frame(width:40, height:40)
            }
            .overlay {
                if isSelected {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(.yellow, lineWidth: 3.0)
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: alignment, content: overlay)
        .onTapGesture {
            isSelected.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct GestureTestView: View {
    @State var indicatorOffset:CGFloat = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentTestView(alignment: .leading) {
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.mint.gradient)
                .frame(width: 8, height: 60)
                .offset(x: indicatorOffset )
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            indicatorOffset = min(max(0, 10 + value.translation.width), 340)
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded { value in
                            
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}


I created minimally reproducible code for the sake of demo. I can not inline the views in real code base. But your answer suggests I need to use View Builder if both the views needs their own gesture recognisers, otherwise its not possible - correct?

@DeepakSharma You don't need to inline the views. Just think of some way to put the overlay before the onTapGesture. Passing the overlay as a ViewBuilder is one way (and IMO makes the most sense), but not the only way.

I see, that's something new for me. Why should it be the case to put overlay before onTapGesture?

@DeepakSharma I don't have an in depth explanation for this, but in general, the .gestures that come before take precedence over the .gestures that come after. Try adding two .onTapGestures consecutively - the first one is always triggered.

Thanks for the answer. I already upvoted and shall wait for 3 days before accepting it (let me see what other developers say).

@DeepakSharma ZStack is different from overlay, in that its size is determined by all of its children. The (logical) size of a.overlay { b } is always just a. I guess in this particular case ZStack is okay, since the overlay has a fixed frame. If the overlay naturally expands to fill all available space, a ZStack would break the layout very badly.

Yes but I see ZStack breaks as well the second time you drag. I think this is a bug in SwiftUI. UIKit is far better where a subview can pass the gesture to superview and even more up in the hierarchy. It seems these things are impossible in SwiftUI.
